# Is liquibase support kerberos authentication with oracle database connection?

Tags: oracle, kerberos, liquibase

Is liquibase support kerberos authentication with oracle database connection?

We are using liquibase node package with version 1.0.1.

If kerberos authentication support with liquibase then please provide details how to use it with oracle database connection.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe Liquibase supports Kerberos authentication.

There's even a Jira ticket to [Include kerberos authentication in Liquibase](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3389), but it's still open and there was no activity yet.

**UPDATE** (Nov 2021)

Looks like the situation has changed and liquibase now do support kerberos.

Check out [Connecting to an Oracle Database with Liquibase via Kerberos and Active Directory](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/connecting-to-an-oracle-database-with-liquibase-kerberos-and-ad.html) article

Comment: Is this still true ? I see this [page](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/connecting-to-an-oracle-database-with-liquibase-kerberos-and-ad.html) that was updated 3 days ago saying it does support kerberos with active directory ?

Comment: oracle active directory link is not working any more